# Determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $x^4-4x^2+2.$

How should I determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$?

Comment: Let $x = \sqrt{-2}$ then ist $x^2 + 2$ the minimal polynomal of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2})$

Comment: I need to determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ instead of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{-2}$.

Comment: First of all, can you determine $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2):

Apply the quadratic formula to $x^4-4x^2+2$ to conclude $x^2 = \frac{4\pm \sqrt{8}}{2}=2\pm\sqrt{2}$.  Since both roots are positive we see that $x^4-4x^2+2$ has $4$ real roots.  Hence the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is $x^4-4x^2+2$

Edit:  Note that $f(x)=x^4-4x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ by Eisenstein's criterion.  Suppose it factored as 2 quadratics, say $g(x)$ and $h(x)$, over $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$  Complex conjugation fixes all the roots of $f$, so $g$ and $h$ are fixed by complex conjugation.  Hence $g$ and $h$ have real coefficients, so $f$ factors over the real subfield of $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$.  But that implies that $f$ factors over $\Bbb{Q}$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why does the fact that the polynomial has four real roots implies that the minimal polynomial is itself?

Comment: To say that I think we need to prove $[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})]=4$?

Comment: Yes, the polynomial has no roots in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$. We still don't know whether it is irreducible. If it can be reduced to two (necessarily second-degree) factors, then one of those would be a minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

Comment: @Arthur Is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$ even a subfield of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$?

Comment: @zerofield That's what I'm saying we need to find out.

Comment: Let K be the splitting field of $x^4-4x^2+2$.  I was thinking it was enough that $K \cap \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]=\Bbb{Q}$, since that means $Gal(K[\sqrt{-2}]/ \Bbb{Q}\sqrt{-2})\simeq Gal(K /\Bbb{Q})$

Comment: The splitting field of $x^4-4x^2+2$ is a totally real field, so $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-2}]$ can't be a subfield.

Comment: A delightful argument!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be a root of the polynomial $x^4-4x^2+2$

$$x^4-4x^2+2$$
$$\left(x^2 - \sqrt{2} -2\right) \left( x^2 + \sqrt{2}  -2\right)$$
$$\left(\sqrt{2 - \sqrt2} - x\right) \left(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt2} - x\right) \left(\sqrt{2 - \sqrt2} + x\right) \left(\sqrt{2 + \sqrt2} + x\right)$$
Then
$$\alpha = \left(\sqrt{2 \pm \sqrt2} \pm x\right) $$

Where the polynomial $\alpha$ has no solutions in $\Bbb{Q}(i\sqrt2)$